# Different runtime behaviour comparing setting breakpoint, and not setting breakpoint (yes really)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging

This is a really strange problem.
I have a python program.
When I step through a specific called function, in debug, it works.
However when I let the ide just run it without stepping (or breakpointing) into it, it raises an exception.

The stacktrace of the exception shows the expected source code.

It's almost like in the step through scenario it calls the correct code, and otherwise it doesn't.

Slightly at my wits end.
Has anyone seen this type of behaviour before?
Thanks
Martin

I've tried deleting the pyc file (the function is in an imported module).
The function started out as an asyncio.async static method. I've "simplified" it to a non-async class instance method.

Comment: It helps if we see the code in question. Or perhaps even better, the full traceback. (The non-async variant is probably preferred.)

Comment: most likely you use the async stuff incorrect, with stepping debugging the async is finished when you reach the line that uses it, without debugging the async function is still not finished when results are needed

Answer (score 0):

I rebooted my pc. Still had the problem. So i moved my try except into the function itself, and also put out some print diagnostics (ie avoiding having to set breakpoints).
This revealed the root of the problem. I had different data the first call time, versus subsequent times. So I can investigate this now.
Humble pie, munch munch munch.